# Variable Replacement in multiple subroutines

Tags: perl

I have a subroutine that I'm trying to pass a string to and used within the subroutine.  A minimal code sample is below.

```
my $printsection="Part";
my @data = qw(12 13 15);

sub heading{
  my $value= $_[0];
  print "$value";
}

sub printdata{
    my $label=$_[0];
    foreach (@data) {
       my $r = $_;
       &heading($label);
    }
}

&printdata("$printsection-$r");
```

What I'm getting is a "Use of uninitialized value $r in concatenation (.) or string at ..." error and I understand why, but I don't know how to fix it in this particular case.  What I'm trying to get out of this is:

```
Part-12
Part-13
Part-15
```

Can someone give me some pointers on how to go about this?

Comment: How do you think the `$_` you are assigning to `$r` is defined and what its value is? If it is not defined then `$r` isn't either.

Comment: Use [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) and [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings). The `$r` used in the last line is not the same `$r` as the one declared in `printdata`, and you haven't assigned it any value.

Comment: I understand what is happening; I'm looking for a way to not evaluate  the variables until &heading function is called.

Comment: Please don't use `&` on subroutine calls. It hasn't been necessary since Perl 5 was released in 1994.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sub printdata {
    my $data      = shift;
    my $formatter = shift;
    for my $r (@$data) {
       print $formatter->($r);
    }
}


my @data = qw(12 13 15);

printdata(\@data, sub { "Part-$_[0]\n" });
```

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for the insightful answer